# Android Studio 1.3 Layout Preview Blue Print

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

In the [Google I/O 2015 - What's new in Android Developer Tools](https://youtu.be/f7ihSQ44WO0?t=37m9s) talk, they mention a feature in Android Studio 1.? that allows you to view a blue print of the layout preview.

It is also mentioned in the [Google I/O summary](http://robovm.com/google-io-summary-whats-new-in-android-development-tools/) page, with an example image:

[image]

Also, in the above article they state:

> The new visual designs haven’t quite made it into Android Studio 1.3...

Does anyone know what release this feature will be available. In particular, I'm on the Beta build of Android Studio 1.3 right now. Is it currently available on any builds, e.g.  Dev or Canary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, **Android 2.2 (stable)** has this feature using which you can see the exact outlines of particular widgets of specific layouts. This will help android developers to get a proper and clean idea about spacing, margins and all .

[image]

for further reading about new features that are included in Android Studio 2.2 , visit developers page http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2016/09/android-studio-2-2.html